# How to edit system emails on SugarCRM CE 6.3?

Tags: settings, sugarcrm

I can't click on the link on the email that SugarCRM sends when the "Assigned User" changes, because it lacks the 'http:' part (starts with //sugarcrmhost.com/blahblah). Is there a way to edit that message so I can force the http://?

I can click on webmail, but not on mail applications (Like thunderbird).

This is the email I receive:

"Some Person has assigned a(n) module_name to Another Person.

You may review this module_name at:

```
//sugarhost.com/crm//index.php?module=module_name&action=DetailView&record=b9ba48d2-2d20-b1fc-a2f8-4e83765f9062
```

Answer (score 1):

The url in the notification emails are based on the following:

```
{$sugar_config['site_url']}/index.php?module={$focus->module_dir}&action=DetailView&record={$focus->id}
```

So check your config files and see what `site_url` is set to.

Comment: one thing to be aware of: Often people prefix their URLs with // instead of explicitly specifying a protocol to avoid mixed content errors (i.e. loading HTTP content on an HTTPS page). By writing your url as //myhost.com/blah the browser will simply inherit the protocol. If you're using https sometimes, consider coding that into your URL or at least testing in IE.